# carriage returns break italics in chat

Tags: support, chat

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1555424#1555424

It seems that if I put carriage returns into chat messages, the chats don't honor the *star* or **double star** markup.

Question: Is this the right place to post such bugs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug - it is by-design. Anything with carriage returns is assumed to be (for example) a paste from some other source, so markdown doesn't *necessarily* apply.

If you want to post a few (separate) lines, just post it as a few subsequent messages.

Comment: why can't I accept your answer now?  dang this low rep! (?)